# How to create tests in C and check the values on Arm neon

Tags: c, compiler-construction, arm, neon

I am trying to write tests in C to check if my understanding of the ARM neon intrinsic are correct. I want to compare my expected output with that from the Arm Neon's. I can complete all ints, uints, polys and float types but I'm unable to do the 2D vector types. The Arm Neon out put claims
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int8x8x2_t'(aka 'struct int8x8x2_t') and 'int8x8x2_t').

Here is my test that I tried to code. I'm also unable to get the printf function out.I understand it has to be a struct, but how do I go about doing this.

```
#include<arm_neon.h>

#include<stdio.h>

int test_vtrn_s8()
{
    int8x8_t a = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 };
    int8x8_t b = { 0xA0, 0xA1, 0xA2, 0xA3, 0xA4, 0xA5, 0xA6, 0xA7 };

    int8x8x2_t want = { {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08},
                        {0xA0, 0xA1, 0xA2, 0xA3, 0xA4, 0xA5, 0xA6, 0xA7} };


    int8x8x2_t result = vtrn_s8( a, b );

    for(int j = 0; j<2; ++j){
        for(int i = 0; i<8; ++i){
            if(want[j][i] != result[j][i] )
                return 1;
            /*printf("result is '0x%d'; and 'expected is 0x%dX\n", result, expected);*/
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
int pass = 0;
pass |= test_vtrn_s8();
return pass;

}
```

Comment: What makes you think you can use `[]` on something which isn't an array (or even a pointer)?

Comment: i was able to use it on 1D vectors so I assumed referencing each element would be like a 2 dimensional array. I'm really stuck on this and not sure what to do.

Comment: Bear in mind that as far as the general sense of "NEON intrinsics" is concerned, you're already well off the map and into [compiler-specific behaviour](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions). Consider using the `vld...()` and `vst...()` operations to move data between vectors and standard C types in the proper, portable, manner.